# How to set maximum and minimum values ​for specific rows and columns with reactiveValues?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

Consider this function:

```
fx <- function(x) {
  
  sapply(X = x, FUN = function(x) {
    
    if (x > 1) {
      
      NULL
      
    } else (x)
    
  })
  
}
```

And this data:

```
set.seed(5)
df_1 <- data.frame(x = replicate(n = 5, expr = runif(n = 5, min = 0, max = 1.7)))
```

Now, I apply the function to a column of this data:

```
fx(df_1[,1])
```

And now, I apply the function in one line.

```
fx(df_1[1,])
```

However, when I try to apply this inside `reactiveValues` ​​I can't get it to work. I think I'm putting it incorrectly inside `observeEvent`.

I would like that, when the user enters values ​​greater than 1 (either in a row or in a column or both selected), the cell is empty again, just like when typing a text (you can test by writing a text in it and you will see that it becomes empty).

My `DT`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Dash", titleWidth = 250)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem(text = "Testar", tabName = "test")))

body <- dashboardBody(
  
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = "test",
      titlePanel("Tabela"),
      fluidPage(
        column(
          width = 3, 
          DT::dataTableOutput("my_datatable")
        )
      )
    )
  )
  
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {
 
  v <- reactiveValues(data = {
    data.frame(y = rep(NA, 30), x = rep(NA, 30))
  })
  
  output$my_datatable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    DT::datatable(
      
      data = v$data,
      editable = TRUE,
      rownames = TRUE,
      selection = list(mode = 'none'),
      
      options = list(
        searching = FALSE,
        paging = FALSE,
        ordering = FALSE,
        info = FALSE,
        autoWidth = TRUE
      )
      
    ) 
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$my_datatable_cell_edit, {
    
    info = input$my_datatable_cell_edit
    
    i = as.numeric(info$row)
    j = as.numeric(info$col)
    k = as.numeric(info$value)
    
    # converter positivos em negativos (se character, o resultado e NULL)
    if (!is.na(k) & k < 0) {
      
      k <- k * -1
      
    } else (k)
    
    v$data[i, j] <- k
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The function I wrote at the beginning of this question I used inside the `observeEvent`, below this one:

```
if (!is.na(k) & k < 0) {
  
  k <- k * -1
  
} else (k)
```

Which works perfectly (and I want to keep it). But, I'd like to add some additional conditions on specific columns and rows, something I haven't been able to do (every time I tried, `DT` crashed and the app crashed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are two issues with your function which result in an error. First, you replace value by `NULL` so your function returns a list instead of a vector. Second, your function does not account of `NA`s in the data table, i.e. as you loop over the vector elements each NA element will give rise to an error when checking `if (x > 1)`. Actually you could rewrite your function more concise and without running in these issues like so:

```
fx <- function(x) {
  x[x > 1] <- NA
  x
}
```

Note: IMHO there is no need for a function which replaces values in a row or column. As the user enters the values per cell it's sufficient to check whether the inputted value is larger than one and replace it with `NA` in case it is, i.e. you could use `if (k > 1) k <- NA` instead.

```
fx <- function(x) {
  x[x > 1] <- NA
  x
}

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Dash", titleWidth = 250)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem(text = "Testar", tabName = "test")))

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = "test",
      titlePanel("Tabela"),
      fluidPage(
        column(
          width = 3,
          DT::dataTableOutput("my_datatable")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {
  v <- reactiveValues(data = {
    data.frame(y = rep(NA, 30), x = rep(NA, 30))
  })

  output$my_datatable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(
      data = v$data,
      editable = TRUE,
      rownames = TRUE,
      selection = list(mode = "none"),
      options = list(
        searching = FALSE,
        paging = FALSE,
        ordering = FALSE,
        info = FALSE,
        autoWidth = TRUE
      )
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$my_datatable_cell_edit, {
    info <- input$my_datatable_cell_edit

    i <- as.numeric(info$row)
    j <- as.numeric(info$col)
    k <- as.numeric(info$value)

    if (!is.na(k) && k < 0) {
      k <- k * -1
    }
    
    v$data[i, j] <- k
    
    v$data[i, ] <- fx(v$data[i, ])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```